# Does the sequence $a_n=n^2 \cos(\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{\pi}{2})$ have a limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Does the sequence $a_n=n^2 \cos(\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{\pi}{2})$ have a limit?

Here we can express $\cos(\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{\pi}{2})$ in terms of $\sin$ and it seems like as $n$ goes to infinity $a_n$ gives infinity$\times$ a finite number. So limit does not exist?

Comment: When $n\to\infty$ the limit $\cos(2/n^2+\pi/2)$ tends to $0$ and $0\times\infty$ is indeterminate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the standard limit $\frac{\sin x}{x}\stackrel{x \to 0}{\longrightarrow}1$ as follows:

$$n^2 \cos(\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{\pi}{2}) = -\frac{\sin \frac 2{n^2}}{\frac 2{n^2}}\cdot 2 \stackrel{n \to 0}{\longrightarrow}-2$$

Answer (score 0):

@trancelocation gave you the simplest way to get the limit.

Let us say that you want a "good" approximation for even small values of $n$
$$a_n=n^2 \cos\left(\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-n^2\sin \left(\frac{2}{n^2}\right)$$ For the time being, let $\frac{2}{n^2}=x$ to make $-2 \frac{\sin(x)}x$ and use the classical Taylor series of the sine this will give
$$-2 \frac{\sin(x)}x=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{2k}$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac{2}{n^2}$ to get
$$a_n=-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{ 2^{2 k}}{(2 k+1)!\, n^{4 k}}$$ Using the first terms
$$a_n=-2+\frac{4}{3 n^4}-\frac{4}{15 n^8}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{12}}\right)$$ which shows for sure the limit and also how it is approached.

But this also gives a good approximation of $a_n$. Use it for $n=10$, the exact value is 
$$a_{5}=-100\sin \left(\frac{1}{50}\right)=-1.999866669333308$$ while the above truncated series would give
$$a_{5}\sim -\frac{749950001}{375000000}=  -1.999866669333333$$